# AWS CLI s3 cp Warning: File Does Not Exist Due to Long File Path on Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-s3

I've been trying to upload a local directory to an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI. While many files upload successfully, I've encountered a warning for specific files:

`warning: Skipping file C:\path\to\long\filename.pdf. File does not exist.`

The file does indeed exist, and the only noticeable difference is that the file path is quite long. How can I resolve this and successfully upload the file?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is due to the default path length limitation of 260 characters in Windows. If a file path exceeds this length, it can lead to problems, as you've experienced with the AWS CLI.

To address this, you can enable long paths on Windows 10 version 1607 and later with the following steps:

1. Press the Windows key and type gpedit.msc, then press Enter. This will open the Local Group Policy Editor.
2. Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.
3. Double-click "Enable NTFS long paths".
4. Select "Enabled", then click OK.

After enabling this, Windows will support longer paths. You should now be able to upload your files to S3 without receiving the warning about the file not existing.